# Assigning a subnet to a sqladmin instance with jinja

Tags: sql-server, jinja2, google-cloud-sql, google-deployment-manager, google-cloud-networking

I have deployed a Google Cloud sqladmin instance (`sqladmin.v1beta4.instance`) and database (`sqladmin.v1beta4.database`), but I now want to assign it to my private subnet. I have done this successfully with multiple VM's but unable to with the sqladmin instance.

This is my current layout for the sqladmin:

```
- name: my-sqladmin-instance
  type: sqladmin.v1beta4.instance
  properties:
    region: europe-west2
    settings:
      tier: db-f1-micro
      backupConfiguration:
        binaryLogEnabled: true
        enabled: true
```

Any help with this would be much appreciated!

Comment: Please elaborate: Are you referring to GCE Instances or Cloud SQL Instances? 
What Private IP? Your project [VPC](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/overview)? or MySQL [Private IP](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/private-ip)?

Comment: @YingLi The private IP I talk about is a subnet with a private IP range. Im refering to [instance](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/admin-api/v1beta4/instances) and [database](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/admin-api/v1beta4/databases)

Answer (score 2):

For CloudSQL, you need a Google Managed Service range allocated in your VPC and then configure the SQL Instance with the VPC Self Link in the PrivateNetwork attribute. More information about GCP Private Services can be found in [GCP VPC Configure Private Services Access](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/configure-private-services-access) and about using them with CloudSQL in [CloudSQL Configure Private IP](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/configure-private-ip).

You can find a template to deploy both configurations in https://github.com/raelga/gcp-dm-templates.

#### Network

```
{% if properties["google-managed-services-range"] %}
- name: google-managed-services-{{ NETWORK }}
  type: compute.v1.globalAddresses
  properties:
    name: google-managed-services-{{ NETWORK }}
    address: {{ properties["google-managed-services-range"].split("/")[0] }}
    prefixLength: {{ properties["google-managed-services-range"].split("/")[1] }}
    addressType: INTERNAL
    purpose: VPC_PEERING
    network: $(ref.{{ NETWORK }}.selfLink)
    description: >
      Address range reserved for Google Managed Services.
      https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/configure-private-services-access
{% endif %}
```

https://github.com/raelga/gcp-dm-templates/blob/master/compute/vpc-network.jinja

#### SQL Instance

And the template for the CloudSQL with the Private Network section:

```
resources:
- name: {{ name }}
  type: sqladmin.v1beta4.instance
  properties:
    backendType: {{ properties['backendType'] }}
...
      {# Connectivity #}
      ipConfiguration:
        ipv4Enabled: {{ properties['publicIp'] }}
        {% if properties['authorizedNetworks'] %}
        authorizedNetworks:
          {% for authorizedNetwork in properties['authorizedNetworks'] %}
          - name: {{ authorizedNetwork.name }}
            cidrBlock: {{ authorizedNetwork.cidrBlock }}
          {% endfor %}
        {% endif %}
        {% if properties['privateIp'] %}
        privateNetwork: {{ "projects/{}/global/networks/{}".format(
          env['project'], properties['privateNetwork']
        ) }}
        {% endif %}
```

https://github.com/raelga/gcp-dm-templates/blob/master/sql/master-instance.jinja

And an example of the template being used for creating a Private CloudSQL instance:

## Network

```
imports:
  - path: ../../../templates/compute/vpc-network.jinja

resources:

- name: vpc-network
  type: ../../../templates/compute/vpc-network.jinja
  properties:
    subnets:
      - name: compute
        range: 10.60.0.0/23
    google-managed-services-range: 10.60.240.0/20
```

https://github.com/raelga/gcp.rael.io/blob/master/dm/deployments/rshared/compute/network.yaml

#### CloudSQL instance

```
imports:
  - path: ../../../templates/sql/master-instance.jinja

resources:
  - name: sites-mysql
    type: ../../../templates/sql/master-instance.jinja
    properties:
      tier: db-f1-micro
      publicIp: false
      privateIp: true
      privateNetwork: rshared-net

outputs:
  - name: connectionName
    value: $(ref.sites-mysql.connectionName)
  - name: ipAddress
    value: $(ref.sites-mysql.ipAddresses[0].ipAddress)
```

https://github.com/raelga/gcp.rael.io/blob/master/dm/deployments/rshared/sql/sites-mysql-cloudsql.yaml

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you are looking for is the **settings.ipConfiguration.privateNetwork** which defines which VPC networks can access the Cloud SQL instance.

> The resource link for the VPC network from which the Cloud SQL instance is accessible for private IP.

You can find the full REST API syntax (which you can use to convert to YAML or jinja) as well as all the fields and their description on the [**sqladmin.v1beta4.instance** method page](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/admin-api/v1beta4/instances). You can also find a list of all supported APIs for Deployment Manager and links to each of their breakdowns on the [Deployment Manager public documentation](https://cloud.google.com/deployment-manager/docs/configuration/supported-resource-types).